# Backbone Marionette Collection Filtering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, marionette

I am trying to allow users to search displayNames and emails in a collection.

So far my entire composite view looks like the code below. This renders and logs my var search, but I'm not sure how to use the collection.where and after the new Backbone.Collection, do I call render?

```
define(["marionette", "text!app/templates/bamboo/employees/collection.html", "app/collections/bamboo/employees",
  "app/views/bamboo/employees/item", "jquery"],
  function(Marionette, Template, Collection, Row, $) {
    "use strict"
    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
      template: Template,
      itemView: Row,
      itemViewContainer: "ul",
      collectionEvents: {
        'sync': 'hideLoading'
      },
      events: {
        'keyup #filter-input': 'initialize'
      },
      initialize: function () {
        var search = $('#filter-input').val()

        if (typeof(search) != "undefined") {
          console.log(search)
          var filtered = //somehow search collection displayName and email by value search
          this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(filtered);
        } else {
          this.showLoading()
          this.collection = new Collection()
          return this.collection.fetch()
        }
      },
      showLoading: function() {
        this.$el.addClass('loading')
      },
      hideLoading: function() {
        this.$el.removeClass('loading')
      }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get views from `Marionette` `CollectionView` and `CompositeView` with `view.children._views`.

With code like this :

```
_.each(colView.children._views,function(v){
  if(!condition){
     v.$el.hide();
  }
});
```

you can hide views in `colView` that has not condition (in your case condition could be `v.model.get('type') == 'todo'`).

Comment: Edited my question. The collection.where isn't quite accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be easier if you only instantiate a single instance of the collection, and then call functions on the models.

```
return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Template,
    itemView: Row,
    itemViewContainer: "ul",
    events: {
        'keyup #filter-input': 'filter'
    },
    initialize: function() {
       this.filter();
    },
    filter: function () {
        var search = $('#filter-input').val() || '';
        this.collection.invoke('set', 'filter', search);
    },
    // ...
});
```

Then, for your itemViews

```
Row = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    modelEvents: {
        "change filter": "filter"
    },
    filter: function(model, search) {
        if (model.shouldBeShown(search)) {
            this.$el.show();
        } else {
            this.$el.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Can you provide a running fiddle? I have http://jsfiddle.net/ysuMZ/2/ that doesn't throw errors, but I don't have enough information for it to run.